# How to still frames to a video with cv2.VideoWriter in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I cannot seem to get `cv2.VideoWriter` to write any frames to a video when the `cv2.VideoWriter` object is passed via a function call. I don't know if it might be an immutable object and that may be the reason?

I know that this works when I just add in random individual frames with no functions used.

I have tried simply returning and storing the VideoWriter object from each function call with no results.

This works:

```py
import cv2

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
vid = cv2.VideoWriter('vid.avi', fourcc, 1, (512, 512))
img = cv2.imread('dog.png')
vid.write(img)
img = cv2.imread('cat.png')
vid.write(img)
vid.release()
```

But this doesn't with a function call with vid as an argument:

```py
import cv2

def add_img(vid):
   img = cv2.imread('dog.png')
   vid.write(img)
   img = cv2.imread('cat.png')
   vid.write(img)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
vid = cv2.VideoWriter('vid.avi', fourcc, 1, (512, 512))
add_img(vid)
vid.release()
```

I don't get any errors but it simply will not add in any images...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the expected behaviour, I have tested the following code and it just works fine. I am creating a random video file of 100 frames which are injected inside a method.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
vid_ = cv2.VideoWriter('/Users/anmoluppal/PycharmProjects/testing/temp/vid.avi', fourcc, 30, (640, 480))


def create_image(vid):
    for i in xrange(100):
        mat = np.random.randint(0, 255, (480,640,3)).astype('uint8')

        vid.write(mat)

create_image(vid_)
vid_.release()
```